# In terminal, how can I write 'sagi' instead of 'sudo apt-get install'

Tags: command-line

I'm tired of always writing `sudo apt-get install <package>` whenever I need to download something, so is there a way for me to make the terminal understand that when I write `sagi <package>`, I really mean `sudo apt-get install <package>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias sagi='sudo apt-get install'
```

Then run `source ~/.bashrc` for the change to take effect.

Alternatively, you could add the line to `.bash_aliases`. This is a nice way to separate simple aliases from more substantive code that you might want to run when you start your bash shell. By default, your `.bashrc` should load in any definitions you make in `.bash_aliases`.

You may not have this file, so first:

```
touch ~/.bash_aliases
```

If the file already exists, touch will simply update its timestamp. If not, it will create it. Either way, open up your favorite text editor and add the alias line from above.

Comment: Actually, `~/.bash_aliases` might be a more proper place.

Comment: You might be right, I'll tweak the answer slightly

Comment: if you use the file **~/.bash_aliases** you have to source it in  **~/.bashrc**, like:

`if [ -f ~/.bash-aliases ]; then . ~/.bash-aliases fi`

Comment: @jarleih I checked mine, it was already in there. I believe it's added by default. But you're right, it's not a guarantee. Things can change